# WordCount with custom word delimiters in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm new to Pig, and I'm trying to write a word count program.

One way of getting words from text is to use the `TOKENIZE` function:

```
WORDS = foreach INPUT generate flatten(TOKENIZE(text)) AS word;
```

But I only want to split on whitespace, whereas `TOKENIZE` splits on things like commas, too. How would I do this? I tried using `STRSPLIT(text, ' ')`, but `STRSPLIT` seems to return a tuple whereas `TOKENIZE` returns a bag, so I'm not sure how to use `STRSPLIT` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually can't directly transform a tuple into a bag (and vice-versa). I suggest you to do this :

1. Load your data
2. Use STRSPLIT to split your value into a tuple
3. Convert your tuples into a bag with an UDF
4. Flatten you bag

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what your input data looks like, but the following could work for you:

1. Use [MyRegExLoader](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MyRegExLoader.java) (in PiggyBank) with a regex to load your data.
2. Use [STREAM](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#STREAM) with Perl, sed, or your favorite scripting language to munge your input data into a format that TOKENIZE will then handle the way you want.

Also, it's possible to convert tuples to a bag with [ToBag](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/util/ToBag.java) (also in PiggyBank).